# How to make a calculated column blank if other columns doesnt have any values?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, isblank

This is my format in the calculated formula:

```
=TEXT([Column2]-[Column1];"hh:mm:ss")
```

I have value "2018-12-13 10:10:23" in `Column1` but when `Column2` is blank the calculated column shows "10:10:23" based of `Column1`.

Is there anyway to make it blank or say some text instead?

Tried this code in calculated column but with no success:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Column2]);"no value";)=TEXT([Column2]-[Column1];"hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF has three parts, condition, result if true, result if false.

```
=IF( a>b, "a is greater", "a is not greater" )
```

So:

```
=IF( ISBLANK(Column2); "no value"; TEXT(Column2-Column1;"hh:mm:ss") )
```

or

```
=IF( ISBLANK(Column2); ""; TEXT(Column2-Column1;"hh:mm:ss") )
```

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked! But for some reason I had to put [ ] in the code. Do you know why? =IF(ISBLANK([Column2);"Inte påbörjat";TEXT([Column2]-[Column1t];"hh:mm:ss"))

Comment: Square brackets are only required when spaces or other special characters are in the column's name.  "Column1", optional, "Column 1" required.